# Destination Host unreachable

Tags: networking, server, dns

I am trying to establish an Ethernet connection, which is enabled. However, when I try to ping my router it says `Destination Host Unreachable`, that means my packages are not being sent over wired, right?

My interfaces config looks like this:

```
auto enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.42
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.1.0
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
    gateway 192.168.1.254
```

Please let me know, whether there is a mistake in the configuration. Or if you have any other ideas.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a "default" route? `ip route` will show you

Comment: Is the configuration active? Please show output of `ip a` and `ip r`. Also, just doublechecking, is your router 1.254?